# Vue.js - Element.io - Composite Key in <el-select>

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When select the option in my application in Vuejs using the framework Element.io, I have the message, because I wanna use the composite key in selected option:

```
Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.
```

I want save array keys in my :key to send form post e.g.:

```
:key="[item.key1,item.key2]"
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/dieterich/pen/jOqzbNY

Answer (score 1):

My solution was create one array of string:

```
:key="`[${item.key1},${item.key2}]`"
```